# How do I access the divs inside a rendered block of radio buttons

Tags: yesod

I noticed radioField gives back a blob that cannot be obviously iterated through via hamlet. I'd like to be able to manipulate the divs inside the blob to make them a css class member. I have thought of two ways. (1) Make a custom form. This seems like overkill to me. (2) Make a hardcoded html form. This seems unsatisfying. I'd like a way to programmatically do it.  Is there an alternative to making a custom form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to make divs members of CSS class, you can instead just wrap the result of selectRadio (do you mean radioField in fact?) in another div.your-class, and use a CSS selector `.your-class div` or `.your-class > div`.  Yes, this is not an answer exactly to your question, but maybe it helps in your problem?

Comment: I think this is what I want, I just have to figure out how to implement your advice.

Comment: in CSS instead of `.myclass {...}` you write `.myclass div {...}`.  In Haskell, having widget of a form, you write `[whamlet|<div.myclass>^{widget}|]` and use it instead of just widget